# "os.environ" in django settings.py cannot get system environment variables with apache and wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, environment-variables, wsgi

I set up the django setting.py like this:

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

The environment variables were configed correctly. When working with the django built in web server, everything was ok. But working with apache and wsgi, it raised an KeyError.

According to [Cannot get environment variables in Django settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395491/cannot-get-environment-variables-in-django-settings-file), the problem is solved. But why cannot apache get the system environment variables?

UPDATED:
The environment variables were set in .bashrc.

Comment: How are you setting those variables? Don't forget Apache will run as its own user.

Comment: By "configured correctly", you mean you use the `SetEnv` directive to set them in your Apache config?  IIRC, Apache clears the environment, so you need to have directives in place to expose the environment variables you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say "The environment variables were set in .bashrc." Presumably you mean *your* .bashrc. Which is pointless, because Apache is not running as you, it is running as the Apache user.

As explained in the blog post referenced in the very question you link to, you need to set the environment variables in the Apache configuration file itself via the `SetEnv` directive.

Comment: Except that SetEnv directive alone does not result in process wide environment variables being set for WSGI applications running under mod_wsgi. It only worked because they were using a WSGI wrapper to read them from the WSGI environ and force setting them on every request. Doing this is actually bad practice and ill advised. It is better to simply set them at the start of the WSGI script file so they are set only once when the WSGI script file is first loaded.

Comment: How to set them at the start of the WSGI script file, Graham?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, curious about this too? How to come about this if we don't maintain multiple wsgi.py files for various environments? THanks.

Answer (score 0):

whatever environments you are setting in the settings.py will be applied for that instance's environment variables only, they are not changing the system env variables which will be called apache.

Comment: if you are working in windows then you can do something like this to set user specific system environment.


`os.system("setx key value")`

Comment: The environment variables were set in .bashrc.