# Set up the Django settings file via DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable with Apache WSGI

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

How to change the settings file used by Django when launched by Apache WSGI only with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable ?

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/) shows how-to achieve this with a different WSGI application file but if we don't want to create a dedicated WSGI file as well as a dedicated settings file for our different environments, using only environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in Apache with `SetEnv` is not sufficent.

The variable is indeed passed to `application` call in `environ` variable but as the `django.conf` retrieve the settings like this :

```
settings_module = os.environ[ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE]
```

it never see the right variable.

Answer (score 9):

As only one instance of a Django application can be run within the context of a Python sub interpreter, the best way of doing things with mod_wsgi would be to dedicate each distinct Django site requiring a different settings, to a different mod_wsgi daemon process group.

In doing that, use a name for the mod_wsgi daemon process group which reflects the name of the settings file which should be used and then at global scope within the WSGI script file, set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` based on the name of the mod_wsgi daemon process group.

The Apache configuration would therefore have something like:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.settings_1
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.settings_2

WSGIScriptAlias /suburl process-group=mysite.settings_2 application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / process-group=mysite.settings_1 application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

and the WSGI script file:

```
import os
try:
    from mod_wsgi import process_group
except ImportError:
    settings_module = 'mysite.settings'
else:
    settings_module = process_group

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = settings_module
```

Comment: Could you expand on what `mod_wsgi` is? Is it a module that can be imported only by the daemon processes or do you mean that we have to install another 3rd party library to access the daemon process group?

Comment: The answer to that is not so simple now. Originally when using Apache/mod_wsgi, importing ``mod_wsgi`` would give you access to a special embedded module added into the running process when Apache/mod_wsgi was used. There is now also a separate ``mod_wsgi`` module that can be installed which is part of ``mod_wsgi-express``. The example above therefore technically needs to change so that it works for both cases.

Comment: Example updated now to work in both cases and still yield same result. Since it is unclear why you are asking, you are better off creating a separate question if there is still something you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you can use the following code in your application's `wsgi.py` file :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

def application(environ, start_response):
    _application = get_wsgi_application()
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

Tip: don't forget to customize the `myapp.settings` string to match your default settings module.

Comment: Setting environment variables on each request like this is actually not a good idea. It gives the wrong impression that ``SetEnv``, which can change the value per request, can be used to dynamically change what settings to use per request when it cannot.