# How to install mod_wgsi for apache 2.4+ with python3.5 on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, python-3.x, centos, mod-wsgi

As title says "How to install mod_wgsi for python3.5 on CentOS 7"?

$pip3.5 install mod_wgsi did not work

```
Collecting mod_wgsi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mod_wgsi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mod_wgsi
```

sudo yum install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 failed too:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * ius: mirror.amsiohosting.net
 * remi: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-php56: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: mirror.daniel-jost.net
No package libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any suggestions on how to run apache2.4+ mod_wsgi with python3.5 on CentOS 7 are very welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see you already have the IUS repo enabled.  Rather than jumping through SCL hoops, you can just install a normal package.

```
yum install python35u-mod_wsgi
```

This will use standard filesystem locations to work with stock Apache HTTPD 2.4.

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi-python3.5.conf
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi_python3.5.so
```

Answer (score 17):

I tried following [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196005/4794), but it didn't solve the problem. It turns out that the version I installed required some extra configuration steps after installation.

#### Background

I looked at Apache's `modules` folder before I installed the `mod_wsgi` upgrade:

```
$ ls -l /lib64/httpd/modules
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 172800 Oct 30 22:44 mod_wsgi.so
```

Then I installed the SCL repository, and looked to see which versions of `mod_wsgi` are available.

```
$ sudo yum install -q -y centos-release-scl
[...]
$ yum search mod_wsgi
[...]
koschei-frontend.noarch : Web frontend for koschei using mod_wsgi
mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
python27-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
python33-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
rh-python34-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
rh-python35-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
rh-python36-mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
viewvc-httpd-wsgi.noarch : ViewVC configuration for Apache/mod_wsgi
[...]
```

I'm using Python 3.6, so I installed the matching version and restarted Apache.

```
$ sudo yum install -q -y rh-python36-mod_wsgi
[...]
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Sadly, that didn't solve the problem. When I looked in Apache's `modules` folder, nothing had changed. Weird!

```
$ ls -l /lib64/httpd/modules
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 172800 Oct 30 22:44 mod_wsgi.so
```

So what did get installed?

```
$ rpm -ql rh-python36-mod_wsgi
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-rh-python36-wsgi.conf
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python36-wsgi.so
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/share/doc/rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/share/doc/rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18/CREDITS.rst
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/share/doc/rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18/LICENSE
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/share/doc/rh-python36-mod_wsgi-4.5.18/README.rst
```

#### Extra Configuration Steps

It installed the files I need, but it didn't put them anywhere useful. With some hints from the `README.rst` file, I copied them into the right place.

```
sudo cp /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python36-wsgi.so /lib64/httpd/modules
sudo cp /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-rh-python36-wsgi.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Now I have the right version of `mod_wsgi`, and my Django app will run under Apache.

Comment: How do you install pip dependencies in this setup? do you have to actually install a Python3.x separate from this package? Isn't python3 binaries already there under /opt/rh/rh-python36?

Comment: I vaguely remember there's a path to the Python executable somewhere in the configuration, @Jose, and I think I pointed that at a virtual environment. If that doesn't help, ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, it's there actually, /opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/(local)/bin

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the **rh-python35** Software Collection which provides a     rh-python35-mod_wsgi package ?

More information about SCL, see:

- [The Software Collection (SCL) Repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL)
- [The Software Collection Special Interest Group](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/SCLo)
- [RHSCL 2.3 release announcement](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-software-collections-23-and-red-hat-developer-toolset-6-now-generally-available)

Comment: Brilliant! Installing Pythion from Software Collection worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [SCL packages for python 3.6](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python36/) (though feel free to substitute 3.5 below).

To start:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install rh-python36 rh-python36-mod_wsgi
```

Note that will bring in the SCL package `httpd24-httpd` and put the mod_wsgi file in that installation.  I would recommend you use that installation and **not** install the base CentOS `httpd` package.  At time of writing, for CentOS 7, the `httpd` package is 2.4.6 and the `httpd24-httpd` package is 2.4.37.

Then you create a virtualenv with:

```
/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python -m venv /path/to/venv36
source /path/to/venv36/bin/activate
pip install ...
```

Now you can put the config for your site in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.conf`, which could contain something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd24/mysite-err.log
    CustomLog  /var/log/httpd24/mysite.log combined

    # recommended way of setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE http://stackoverflow.com/a/25496668/3189
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.settings.production
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.settings.production python-path=/path/to/mysite/:/path/to/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=mysite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you start the SCL apache with:

```
systemctl start httpd24-httpd
```

And your site should be working.