# httpd mod_wsgi for python3.4 not working in centos7

Tags: apache, python-3.4, mod-wsgi, centos7

I've Django application running in centos7 using python3.4. I'm using apache for webserver. BUt i'm getting following errors:

```
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.048763 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100] mod_wsgi (pid=8470): Target WSGI script '/var/www/hello_world_django/hello_world_django/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049021 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100] mod_wsgi (pid=8470): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/hello_world_django/hello_world_django/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049272 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049383 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]   File "/var/www/hello_world_django/hello_world_django/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049625 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049661 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]   File "/var/www/virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049711 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049735 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]   File "/var/www/virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049777 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100]     @functools.lru_cache()
[Tue Dec 05 09:48:17.049901 2017] [:error] [pid 8470] [remote 103.194.69.2:100] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

There seems to be some issue with mod_wsgi for python3.4. To check that i tried it with python2.7 and its working for pythyon2.7.

I'm not able to find a mod_wsgi package for python3.4 in centos. Any iseas how to fix this????

Here is my apache conf

```
Listen 8080
# Django settings

WSGIDaemonProcess django_com user=apache group=apache processes=1 threads=10 python-path=/var/www/sample:/var/www/sample_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup django_com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/sample/sample/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/sample>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you sure mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 3.4. If it has been compiled for 2.7, you can make it use a virtual environment for Python 3.4.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton how can i check if its complied with python 2.7, I just install mod_wsgi and setup apaceh2. I'm updating my apache conf now.

Comment: If you installed mod_wsgi using a system package, what was the name of the package. Did it mention Python 3 in the name? Otherwise follow procedures in documentation for working it out. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i didnt install mod_wsgi package for python3.4. Can you tell me how to do IT.

Comment: Look first whether your operating system provides a py3 version of the mod_wsgi package.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004986/how-to-install-mod-wgsi-for-apache-2-4-with-python3-5-on-centos-7 Is there a reason it must be Python 3.4 as that is old.

Comment: I've written up how to do this with SCL at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830759/3189

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get Python 3.4 working with mod_wsgi in CentOS, assuming you have Python 3.4 (and pip) installed from EPEL, you can do this:

`yum install httpd-devel` (you need this for the pip installation of mod_wsgi to work)

`pip3 install mod-wsgi`

`mod_wsgi-express install-module > /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/02-wsgi.conf`

Comment: I don't know why this isn't in the documentation, but it should be.