# Django + mod_wsgi. Set OS environment variable from Apache's SetEnv

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I need to split Django's development and production settings. I decided that if `USKOVTASK_PROD` variable is set, then app should use production settings. I read [this](http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/nov/12/apache-environment-variables-and-mod_wsgi/) article and tried to do it.

My snippets:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/uskovtask.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName uskovtask.*.com
ServerAlias uskovtask.*.com
DocumentRoot /mnt/ebs/uskovtask


Alias /static /mnt/ebs/uskovtask/static/
<Directory /mnt/ebs/uskovtask/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#WSGIPythonPath /mnt/ebs/uskovtask
WSGIDaemonProcess uskovtask.*.com python-path=/mnt/ebs/uskovtask:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup uskovtask.*.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /mnt/ebs/uskovtask/uskovtask/wsgi.py
SetEnv USKOVTASK_PROD 1


<Directory /mnt/ebs/uskovtask/uskovtask>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "uskovtask.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
    if 'USKOVTASK_PROD' in environ:
        os.environ.setdefault('USKOVTASK_PROD', environ['USKOVTASK_PROD'])
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

**settings.py's part:**

```
import os

if 'USKOVTASK_PROD' in os.environ:
    from settings_prod import *
else:
    from settings_dev import *
```

But it always imports settings_dev's settings. Why?

Comment: Can you debug and verify if USKOVTASK_PROD really sets in os.environ ? You can place a simple print for that.

Comment: @iamkhush USKOVTASK_PROD is in os.enivron if I print it in `wsgi.py`, but not in `settings.py`

Comment: Can you verify if the statement "if 'USKOVTASK_PROD' in environ" is true by placing print after it.

Comment: @iamkhush it is False

Comment: Ok, then its clear that the problem is with apache conf file not settings the variable correctly.

Comment: @iamkhush Oh, no, sorry, it is True, but `'USKOVTASK_PROD' in os.environ` in `settings.py` is False

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65099/discussion-between-iamkhush-and-michaeluskov).

Comment: Sorry. This has nothing to do with the answer. But it is a really bad idea to post the URL to a django site which you have running with DEBUG=True. Please edit your answer and replace your URLs with something like blabla.myproject.com or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to question [Access Apache SetEnv variable from Django wsgi.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754834/access-apache-setenv-variable-from-django-wsgi-py-file)

You need to inherit WSGIHandler as the answer says.

As Graham Dumpleton explains in the second answer,

> That all said, the blog post you mention will not usually help. This
>   is because it is using the nasty trick of setting the process
>   environment variables on each request based on the per request WSGI
>   environ settings set using SetEnv in Apache. This can cause various
>   issues in a multi threading configuration if the values of the
>   environment variables can differ based on URL context. For the case of
>   Django, it isn't helpful because the Django settings module would
>   normally be imported before any requests had been handled, which means
>   that the environment variables would not be available at the time
>   required.

and I think this is what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by changing **wsgi.py** to this:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
import django
import os

class WSGIEnvironment(WSGIHandler):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        os.environ['USKOVTASK_PROD'] = environ['USKOVTASK_PROD']
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "uskovtask.settings")
        django.setup()
        return super(WSGIEnvironment, self).__call__(environ, start_response)

application = WSGIEnvironment()
```

Comment: Can confirm that this worked for me with Apache/2.2.22 (Debian), mod_wsgi/4.4.8, Python/3.4.2, Django/1.7.3 (Of course, after changing 'USKOVTASK_PROD' and 'uskovtask.settings' to match my ENV variable and app name.)

Comment: I was using Django 1.6 and env vars were working fine, then I updated to Django 1.8 and env vars weren't loading at all and I was given default values everywhere... Then I found your answer! I guess this is the route to go for Django > 1.6, thanks!