# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE envar not getting set

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I am currently developing an application in Python 3.6 and Django 1.11, on the production server (Ubuntu 16.04) I am using Apache2.

I am trying to use separated settings for production and development. Instead of a file, I have a settings directory with base setttings, and production and development settings file, which import the base settings and potentially override them. To let Django know which settings to use, I am setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to either `prehranske_oznacbe.settings.development` or  `prehranske_oznacbe.settings.production`. This works fine for development. Concerning setting the envvars on the production server, I followed the answers to these two SO: 
[Access Apache SetEnv variable from Django wsgi.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754834/access-apache-setenv-variable-from-django-wsgi-py-file), [Django + mod_wsgi. Set OS environment variable from Apache's SetEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979579/django-mod-wsgi-set-os-environment-variable-from-apaches-setenv).

The problem is, when I try to acces my application, I get a 500 Internal Error. The apache error logs:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=404): Target WSGI script '/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/prehranske_oznacbe/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=404): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/prehranske_oznacbe/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/prehranske_oznacbe/wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
     application = WSGIEnvironment()
   File "/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 48, in load_middleware
     if settings.MIDDLEWARE is None:
   File "/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting MIDDLEWARE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

as if the envvar DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not getting set. My code:

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/static
    <Directory /home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/prehranske_oznacbe>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess prehranske_oznacbe python-path=/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe python-home=/home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup prehranske_oznacbe
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/inesmersak/prehranske_oznacbe/prehranske_oznacbe/wsgi.py

    # Envvars for Django aplication 'Prehranske oznacbe'.
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE prehranske_oznacbe.settings.production
    SetEnv OZNACBE_API_USERNAME (redacted)
    SetEnv OZNACBE_API_PASSWORD (redacted)
    SetEnv OZNACBE_SECRET_KEY (redacted)
</VirtualHost>
```

*wsgi.py*

```
import os
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler


class WSGIEnvironment(WSGIHandler):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'prehranske_oznacbe.settings.production')
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
        os.environ['OZNACBE_SECRET_KEY'] = environ['OZNACBE_SECRET_KEY']
        os.environ['OZNACBE_API_USERNAME'] = environ['OZNACBE_API_USERNAME']
        os.environ['OZNACBE_API_PASSWORD'] = environ['OZNACBE_API_PASSWORD']
        django.setup()
        return super(WSGIEnvironment, self).__call__(environ, start_response)

application = WSGIEnvironment()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetEnv` does not set process wide environment variables for a WSGI application, it sets the per request WSGI environ variables passed in the `environ` dictionary to the WSGI application with the request. That WSGI application entry point is called after Django has been initialised though, so setting `os.environ` with that at that point is too late. It is also regarded as bad practice to update `os.environ` on a per request basis. Using a separate WSGI script file is better.

```
# production.wsgi

import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '....'
....

from prehranske_oznacbe.wsgi import application
```

And have `WSGIScriptAlias` reference `production.wsgi` file by path.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and a nice solution!