# Key error while trying to access custom environment variable in Django application on a virtual machine running Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtual-machine, gunicorn

I have set an environment variable on my VM as follows (in my virtual env):

```
$ export MYSQL_USER="naitik"
```

Also when I tried to echo the value on terminal, it is showing correct output:

```
$ echo $MYSQL_USER
  naitik
```

Even when I printed the value on python interpreter on the terminal, it is showing correct output.
But when I tried to use it in my Django application, it is showing error.

settings.py file where I have tried to use the environment variable:

```
  DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '<myhost>',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'ndt_db',
            'USER': os.environ["MYSQL_USER"],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
        }
    }
```

Error log from gunicorn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/diamond-tools-website/naitikdiamondtools/naitikdiamondtools/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/diamond-tools-website/naitikdiamondtools/naitikdiamondtools/settings.py", line 104, in <module>
    'USER': os.environ["MYSQL_USER"],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MYSQL_USER'
[2020-06-07 07:03:38 +0000] [1619] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1619)
[2020-06-07 07:03:38 +0000] [1620] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/diamond-tools-website/naitikdiamondtools/naitikdiamondtools/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/diamond-tools-website/naitikdiamondtools/naitikdiamondtools/settings.py", line 104, in <module>
    'USER': os.environ["MYSQL_USER"],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MYSQL_USER'
[2020-06-07 07:03:38 +0000] [1620] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1620)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
    self.sleep()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
    ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1945, in shutdown
    h.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 978, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Comment: maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26979579/13168118

Comment: I'm using Nginx server not apache. Will this solution still work?